# Checking if a parameter dependent integral is differentiable

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

I was asked recently to show that $F(t) := \int_0^{\infty} \cos(tx)e^{-x^2/2}dx$ is differentiable. This is for a class on Lebesgue integrals. We also covered Lebesgue's FTOC (not sure if that matters).

Here is my attempt at a solution:
We have to compute the limit:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(t+h) - F(t)}{h} $$
and see if it exists. Substituting in the formula for $F$, we get:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\frac{\cos((t+h)x)-\cos(tx)}{h}dx $$
Take an arbitrary sequence $(h_n)_1^{\infty}$ converging to 0. We get that the above is equal to:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\frac{\cos((t+h_n)x) - \cos(tx)}{h_n}dx $$
Note $\cos(tx)e^{-x^2/2}\chi_{[0,n]}\to  \cos(tx)e^{-x^2/2}$ and $|\cos(tx)e^{-x^2/2}\chi_{[0,n]}|\leq e^{-x^2/2}$ which is certainly integrable on $[0,\infty)$. Thus, we use DCT to get:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cos((t+h_n)x) - \cos(tx)}{h_n})dx $$
which is equivalent to saying:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}(\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\cos((t+h)x) - \cos(tx)}{h})dx $$
We know the derivative of $\cos(tx)$ taken with respect to $x$ is simply $(-t)\sin(tx)$. Thus, we get:
$$ F'(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(t+h) - F(t)}{h} = -\int_0^{\infty} t\sin(tx)e^{-x^2/2}dx $$
Thus $F'(t)$ existing comes down to showing that $t\sin(tx)e^{-x^2/2}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$. This is true so $F'(t)$ exists. Thus $F$ is differentiable.

I used some assumptions here that I am not sure work out. For example, I presume since I kept $h_n$ to be an arbitrary sequence covering to 0, I can swap $\lim_{h\to 0}$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}$. Any criticism is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\frac {dF}{dt}  = \int_0^\infty -x\sin (xt) e^{-x^2}\ dx$

Comment: oh right so I am not differentiating w.r.t x? Then the derivative of $\cos(xt)$ should be $-x\sin(tx)$ ? Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: You are differentiating with respect to $t.$  Which you are doing correctly in the preliminary step.

Comment: Use the formula to combine $$\cos((t+h)x)-\cos(th)=...$$ and calculate the limit by using this formula.

Comment: Right yes. I think I just confused myself. Thank you for the help. Is there anything that you think looks odd ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the limit just represents differentiation so I thought I could just differentiate it (once I know that what I am taking the limit of is differentiable). Is that not ok ?

Comment: Befor you can differentiate you must show that the limit for $t$ tends to zero exists.

Comment: ok that is fair. I will do that thank you!